# JQuery AJAX Post - pass variable and navigate URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, post

I am developing a small puzzle. Users click on blocks of a picture and guess what picture it is. I also count how many blocks they opened before submitting. I use following JQuery AJAx code in VBScript/ASP

```
dataString  = 'totalClick=' + totalClick ;

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "puzzle3.asp",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {
        alert('totalClick' + totalClick + "data: " + dataString );
        window.location = "puzzle3.asp";
    }  
});
```

My problem is, I want to get value of 'totalClick' variable on 'puzzle3.asp' page. After I navigate to 'puzzle3.asp', I want to use it there to decide some other stuff. But here as soon as I navigate to puzzle3.asp via AJAX, i lost value of POST variable 'totalClick'.

Is there some way I can use POST, navigate to next page and use variable vlaue there. Just like setting a session variable but I understand i can not assign session variable using JS.

Any help would be appreciated much.

Comment: Just use ASP to set the session variable and then navigate to `puzzle3.asp`, and pull the session variable out with ASP.

Comment: If your are doing a Window.location, why use ajax in the first place?

Comment: @loddn's comment is the most appropriate action, considering that code. Maybe the OP needs more enlightenment. All the answers, to me, seem to encourage doing simple things in a complex way. KISS, remember. SO is not about providing code; it's about guiding.

Answer (score -1):

from jquery doc:

> dataObject, String
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

have you tried manually placing your variable into the query string?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "puzzle3.asp?totalClick=" + totalClick,
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        alert('totalClick' + totalClick + "data: " + dataString );
        window.location = "puzzle3.asp";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am afraid I can not use POST as I want to hide my 'totalClick' variable due to business needs. That is all creating problem for me. so I can not use above Querystring.

Comment: Why use ajax if you are doing a window.location on uour success?

Answer (score -1):

Try saving your variables via POST, load the new page and retrieve the variable using AJAX, something like:

Page A:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "puzzle3.asp",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        alert('totalClick' + totalClick + "data: " + dataString );
        window.location = "puzzle3.asp";
    }
});
```

Page B (puzzle3.asp):

```
/**
 * No need to wait for load() event, just generate a
 * global variable with the number of clicks
 */
(function($){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "read_clicks.asp",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // Use any global variable, as needed
            $.totalClicks = data.clicks || 0;
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var ssnData="123";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'SSNdata': ssnData }),
    url: 'home/data',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (cicos) {
        //cicos is your response data
    }
});
```