# jQuery AJAX Navigate as POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I want a web page, which when a button is pressed, the browser navigates to a URL with method POST, and some xml data as the request content. The response will also be xml. My question is similar to [JQuery AJAX Post - pass variable and navigate URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642614/jquery-ajax-post-pass-variable-and-navigate-url) , but the answers to that question do an ajax POST, followed by navigation to a GET of the URL, whereas I want a direct navigation via POST.

### What I have tried so far?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Entry page</title>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function LogIn() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Login/" + $( "#User" ).val(),
    data: '<m:password xmlns:m="http://acme.com">' + $( "#Password" ).val()  + "</m:password>",
    method: 'POST',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success :function()
      {
        alert('Ok');
        window.location="http://localhost:8080/Login/" + $( "#User" ).val();
      },
      error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(thrownError);
} });
}
</script>
  </head>
 <body>
<form>
  <label>User<input id="User" type="text" value="Sean" name="User"/></label>
  <label>Password<input id="Password" type="password" name="Password"/></label>
</form>

<button onclick="LogIn()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

### Cross Domain

I realise that this is cross domain. The server has been configured to allow this, and the cross-domain bit works perfectly well.

### What is the issue?

The `$.ajax()` call simply invokes the POST, it doesn't navigate to it. Setting the `window.location` doesn't help, because this is a content-less GET, not a data-loaded POST.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Solved thanks to https://formkeep.com/guides/submit-form-with-ajax

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Entry page</title>
  <script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
// Thanks to https://formkeep.com/guides/submit-form-with-ajax
$(function() {
  $('#form3').submit(function(event) {
    var formEl = $(this);
    var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/Login/" + $( "#User" ).val();
    var datum = '<m:password xmlns:m="http://acme.com">' + $( "#Password" ).val()  + "</m:password>";

    $('#x').val(datum);
    $("#form3").attr("action", url);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: datum,
      dataType: "xml",
      contentType: "application/xml",
      beforeSend: function() {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
      error   :function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
        },
      done: function() {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
      }
      });
  });
});
  </script>
</head>



<body>

<form id="form3" action="set-dynamically" method="POST">
  <label>User<input id="User" type="text" value="Sean" name="User"/></label>
  <label>Password<input id="Password" type="password" name="Password"/></label>
  <textarea style="display:none" name="x" id="x">
    <m:password xmlns:m="http://acme.com">Password</m:password>
  </textarea>
  <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It navigates but I'm receiving null values. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The post request is posting the data to:

> http://localhost:8080/Login/" + $( "#User" ).val()

This is on you local host so you should have a server side route on you application to catch this ajax post request and send a success/message back back. Try passing in a "data" parameter into your success function and see what it logs.

Comment: I've done this. The server application returns the correct response, and I can successfully capture it in the browser console or a javascript variable. The problem is that the browser is `just` posting to this url, **not** navigating to it.

Comment: I want the browser to **navigate** to `http://localhost:8080/Login/Sean` as a POST with payload xml data.

Comment: then you need to do another get request at the success of the original ajax. Then your route should render the page. Or you could try rendering the page at your post route, but I've never tried that.